# What is the name of the path helper for a sign_in page in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I couldn't really find this in the documentation. Only thing I've found is a `after_sign_in_path_for` method. What I want though is something like `sign_in_path_for(:account)` so that I wouldn't have to hardcode "/account/sign_in" path in. Any ideas if Devise has this kind of thing?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

this depends on the scope, if yours is 'account' then

```
new_account_session_path
```

you can see all the routes that devise creates doing a

```
$ rake routes
```

Comment: `rake routes` is a great but if you have a lot of routes it might be hard to find what you need quickly. You may want to filter it like this - `rake routes | grep sign`

Comment: In Rails 5+, I'd recommend: `bin/rails routes -g session`

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone new coming here, what worked for me was using

```
new_user_session_path
```

And for seeing the routes I used

```
rails routes
```

And to only see the routes containing user I ran

```
rails routes | grep users
```

I guess it's different now in Rails 7.